# Explicit return type breaks generic typing of function

Tags: typescript

I'm having a typescript issue which I've already reduced down to a minimum reproducible example:

```
interface FooOptions<T> {
    arg: T;
    handler: (ctx: T) => void;
}

interface FooResult<O extends FooOptions<unknown>> {
    optionsUsed: O;
}

function fooWorks<T>(options: FooOptions<T>) {
    return { optionsUsed: options };
}

function fooBreaks<O extends FooOptions<unknown>>(options: O): FooResult<O> {
    return { optionsUsed: options };
}

const worksResult = fooWorks({
    arg: { some: 'stuff' },
    handler(ctx){
        console.log(ctx.some);
        return true;
    }
});

const result = fooBreaks({
    arg: { some: 'stuff' },
    handler(ctx){
        // I want this to typecheck
        console.log(ctx.some);
        return true;
    }
});

// and this should be inferred automatically
type ThisShouldBeBoolean = ReturnType<typeof result.optionsUsed.handler>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0HkAOZjogDOAPACoB8yA3gFDIPJxQDmAXMmQNz2MAWcEABMANtA4AKBGAAeHMgEpkAXioA3dMCE8AvrVqhIsRCgzoAShCIBXEWBJZkEGZGFE0mXPkKlrIANYg6ADuIBRUdIzI6HgExACqRBBCHFi6+jB+0nHIMJgA6uhQ-qSUEjHexBxmXnGlFEqRjFAQYNZQIDTRsT6JyRwVdcg66bSZINmEuZgAQi1wJQ5OLhBuHtg9xCR+gSFhFOWbRKkK1ZiWNnYOEbwMLW0dXYO9SSndle4jtHpjBUUlEiaDGY7C6RHQAFsIBwAORENowGAw4YAGluyAEwjEUCksgUQKiyAQPnQYgAdCJ0CxcTIyeCoQoeFE9DpGb90HMIAsiID0SCONRkPTocg4Qikaj0ZjRNAafj0VFicRSRAKVSaXTIRA2czvoygA)

For the definition of the `fooWorks` function I let typescript infer the return type and it works correctly as expected.

The actual implementation of `fooWorks` is much more complex than that and I can't rely on type inference to get the type right, so I actually need to type it explicitly - I've been trying to do that with the `fooBreaks` function, but as you can see in the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0HkAOZjogDOAPACoB8yA3gFDIPJxQDmAXMmQNz2MAWcEABMANtA4AKBGAAeHMgEpkAXioA3dMCE8AvrVqhIsRCgzoAShCIBXEWBJZkEGZGFE0mXPkKlrIANYg6ADuIBRUdIzI6HgExACqRBBCHFi6+jB+0nHIMJgA6uhQ-qSUEjHexBxmXnGlFEqRjFAQYNZQIDTRsT6JyRwVdcg66bSZINmEuZgAQi1wJQ5OLhBuHtg9xCR+gSFhFOWbRKkK1ZiWNnYOEbwMLW0dXYO9SSndle4jtHpjBUUlEiaDGY7C6RHQAFsIBwAORENowGAw4YAGluyAEwjEUCksgUQKiyAQPnQYgAdCJ0CxcTIyeCoQoeFE9DpGb90HMIAsiID0SCONRkPTocg4Qikaj0ZjRNAafj0VFicRSRAKVSaXTIRA2czvoygA), TS isn't happy :/

I've already tried introducing another type parameter to capture the actual type used going into `FooOptions`, but when I do that, suddenly the return type inference breaks.

Any ideas how I could let typescript correctly accept my explicit type to make it work exactly like the inferred one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
interface FooOptions<T> {
    arg: T;
    handler: (ctx: T) => void;
}

interface FooResult<O> {
    optionsUsed: FooOptions<O>;
}

function fooWorks<T>(options: FooOptions<T>) {
    return { optionsUsed: options };
}

function fooBreaks<O>(options: FooOptions<O>): FooResult<O> {
    return { optionsUsed: options };
}

fooWorks({
    arg: { some: 'stuff' },
    handler(ctx){
        console.log(ctx.some);
    }
});
fooBreaks({
    arg: { some: 'stuff' },
    handler(ctx){
        console.log(ctx.some);
    }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0HkAOZjogDOAPACoB8yA3gFDIPJxQDmAXMmQNz2MAWcEABMANtA4AKBGAAeHMgEpkAXioA3dMCE8AvrVqhIsRCgzoAShCIBXEWBJYqdRsnR4CxAKpEIQjmdx8QlJHXX0YaxBpD2QYTAB1dCgAa1JKCTcg4n9MQI80iiVnRigIMGsoEBpXd2DvXw5M-OQdMNoIqKzYzAAhUrhUhwoM2uy0XNGQwpyLK1t7RxpeBlLyyuqmup8-GqyiFra49ESUoglihmZ2aqJ0AFsIDgByInKYGCeWgBpl5AFhMRQKSyBQXFzIBDBdBiAB0InQLGBMhhtweCh4Lj0OnR7V6-VS51%20Vw41GQqMeyBebw%2031%20-1E0CRoN%20LkhxGhEDhCKRKPuEBxmNo2K4QA)